# A question on the isomorphism between two quotient rings.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Are the rings $Z[x]/(x^2+7)$
and $Z[x]/(2x^2+7)$
isomorphic?

Is it legitimate to answer this by First Isomorphism Theorem? They are isomorphic iff the homomorphisms $\pi_1: Z[x]\rightarrow Z[x]/(x^2+7)$ and $\pi_2: Z[x]\rightarrow Z[x]/(2x^2+7)$ have the same kernel which is impossible. So they are not isomorphic. I am not sure that my solution is correct.

Comment: Why do you claim that they are isomorphic if and only if $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ have the same kernels?

Comment: The two projections $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z$ have different kernels, yet their images are isomorphic (one might even say they are _equal_).

Comment: Two distinct ideals could lead to isomorphic quotient rings. For example, for any commutative ring $R$ and any $a,b \in R$, $R[x]/(x-a)$ and $R[x]/(x-b)$ are both isomorphic to $R$.

Comment: Thanks, now I know that images of two homomorphisms are isomorphism if they have the same kernel but not only if. And I found another solution intuitively: the nonzero residue of x squared plus 7 of Z[x] is all the polynomials with degree 1 or 0, but the residue of 2 times x squared plus 7 can be of polynomial with higher degree like x^6, which cannot be killed by 2 x squared plus 7. So they are not isomorphic.

Comment: And those two quotient rings can be seen as the integer ring adjoining some elements. In the former case, the element has property: $x^2+7=0$, and in the latter one, the property becomes: $2x^2+7=0$.